# Visual Studio Solution Explorer Randomly Expanding Projects

Tags: visual-studio

The folders under my solution in the Solution Explorer window randomly expand.  This happens everytime I load the project, and randomly as I use Visual Studio 2008.  The behavior seems to have no real pattern, and it's like it has a mind of it's own.  Any ideas on what I can do to keep behaving like you would imagine it should (expand/collapse only when the + or - is clicked on)?

Comment: I've had this happen before too in VS2008 - typically for me it's when I debug something and the dynamic versions of the code load (run-time javascript and such), it will expand some (or often all) of the subfolders in my project.

Comment: you don't use "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" or so?

Answer (score 10):

Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, General.  "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" option.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know about that.  It is however unchecked yet the behavior is still as I described above.

Comment: I can't believe that this option was so annoying to me that I had to google it. Thanks for that!

Comment: -1 because it doesn't indicate whether I need to check it or uncheck it.  It would be nice to find an answer that explains what the option means because it is not self explanatory.

Comment: I like the feature, others hate it.  That's why it is an option.  I'm not going to tell you to like it, that will get me entirely too many nasty comments that point out I'm stoopid.  I now only have to put up with comments from programmers that can't think for themselves.